# Unable to find LoginModule class: com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixLoginModule

Tags: java, security, hadoop, authentication, kerberos

Trying to access HDFS location using Kerberose authentication, but getting below error message:

```
java.io.IOException: failure to login
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:839)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:775)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:648)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2859)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2851)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2714)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:382)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:181)
        at com.xyz.module.submodule.common.utils.HDFSPropertyLookup.loadProperties(HDFSPropertyLookup.java:75)
        at com.xyz.module.submodule.common.utils.HDFSPropertyLookup.initialize(HDFSPropertyLookup.java:37)
        at com.xyz.module.submodule.common.utils.HDFSPropertyLookupTest.initializePropertiesFile(HDFSPropertyLookupTest.java:16)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class: com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixLoginModule
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:794)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:813)
        ... 31 more
```

Cause: `LoginModule class: com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixLoginModule` not found.

Want to know in which `.jar` file `com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixLoginModule` is present?

If someone might have faced this issue before, then please let help!

Comment: missing jar is rt.jar. its from jre/lib

Comment: rt.jar is present at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\rt.jar

Comment: Go into Configure Build Path on the project and go to the Libraries tab and then system library then check for rt.jar

Comment: Using eclipse it is running in my machine, but from command prompt its not running.

Comment: post your pom.xml

Comment: Did you set JAVA_HOME?

Comment: set as JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161155/discussion-between-farooque-and-vts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue got resolved!

Let me share the real cause and how it got resolved?

In unit test code, I was setting the `os.name` system property value to different operating system for my test case scenario as below:

```
System.setProperty("os.name", "Windows");
```

I was setting above properties value with Windows/Unix/MAC etc, but I missed to reset to its original value.

In same project there I was executing `FileSystem.get(new Configuration());` from Hadoop API, in which Kerberose authentication was set.

So while execution operating system name was getting changed to some other name and it was not reset to original name.

**Solution:**

So in setup method I collected the original OS name to some other variable and after all test case completion reset to original name as below:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setup() throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("os.name.orig", System.getProperty("os.name"));

}

// other test case methods continue...

@AfterClass
public static void clearProperties() throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("os.name", System.getProperty("os.name.orig"));
    System.clearProperty("os.name.orig");
}
```

After above setting OS was reverted back to its original name and everything started working properly.

Hope this will help others in future!!!

Comment: Nice job.  Please self-accept your own answer. You might be forced to wait two days before SO allows the self-accept, but this will help better signpost the question to people searching about this question on Google.